# One link (onclick) changes two attributes

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, onclick

I am struggling with making the link change two attributes in the page:

a) I got a select box that changes the value of a YouTube video and loads it.

```
function loadVideo() {
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("videoSelection");
  var videoID = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value

  if(ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
  }
}
```

```
            <select id="videoSelection" onchange="loadVideo();">
              <option value="ylLzyHk54Z0" selected>YouTube API Overview</option>
              <option value="muLIPWjks_M">Ninja Cat</option>
              <option value="GMUlhuTkM3w">Beatboxing Flute</option>
            </select>
```

b) I realized that in the moment of change I need to change the content of div bellow the video div.

c) Is there a way to make one link (not a select box anymore) change the attributes of div and video?

Comment: So am I right in thinking you actually need a link to be clicked and the youtube video to change and also you need the content of the div to change too? Where is this div content coming from? for example is the content placed into the page from the server or from a CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have:

```
<a href="#" class="videoLink" data-video="ylLzyHk54Z0">YouTube API Overview</a>
```

You can use JQuery to detect a click on a video link and use its data attribute to pull through the desired video id:

```
$(".videoLink").on("click", function () {
    var videoId = $(this).data('video');
    loadVideo(videoId);
    //Also load in the content you need into the div here
});
```

Then this would be your video load function:

```
function loadVideo(videoID) {

  if(ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
  }
}
```

As I am not sure where your extra div content is coming from or how this would look in your HTML, it is hard to advise you how to implement this.

For example if the content was in the page already you could simply show and hide the correct div or block of information inside the div. Or if you wanted you could use an AJAX call to grab the content you needed and inject it into the div, replacing current content if some already in there.

For purpose of this example I have created a JSFiddle and added in a simple div with an extra description data attribute and added a changeDescription function in this [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/3y5EW/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I cannot manage to get it work. The click on the link does not really do anything. The extra content I want to load with the video will be placed in the div "description" under the video, so the link should have an attribute where I can insert it. (Eg.: description="...")

Comment: here is an example (working, minus the youTube specific part): http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/3y5EW/

Comment: Thanks again, but still I got an error. Could it be that the jQuery version is too old? My code is here. http://ilovesegway.com/hadry/index.php

Comment: To be honest it looks like you have quite a few errors in your JS formatting. If you run your JS through a JS linter you will see it has loads of issues. Whilst these problems exist, your JS will not function as you expect.

Comment: paste your JS code in here and look at the errors you get: http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Just as a few quick pointers, the loadVideo function has an extra } . Your loadPlayer method has a var statement without a semi-colon at the end. Also your code has a mix of formatting, spaces and tab spaces, possibly coming in form cutting and pasting code. Might be an idea to paste all your code into an editor of your choice and unify it. I think also you could benefit from loading all of your javascript on document ready, unless specifically needing code to run as the browser gets to it.

Comment: Thanks, I was experimenting with my code and noticed that it stops working when I uncomment `$(window).load(function(){
function loadVideo(videoID) {
    alert(videoID);
    
    //Commented out youtube player code for JSFiddle example
    //Replace to test with your own youTube JS running also
    
  //if(ytplayer) {
    //ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
  //}
}`